# I have prototyped a function but my class still says it is not a member?

Tags: c++, nodes

I am making a function that removes the head node of a linked list and makes it the head of another linked list. I prototyped a function called moveNode in the outerclass called LinkedList, and I defined the function later on in my code. However, my compiler gives me error messages saying "class LinkedList::Node is private" and "LinkedList::Node* LinkedList:head is private. I don't understand what I need to do to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


class LinkedList 
{ 
public: 
    LinkedList() { head = NULL; } // default constructor 

    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const LinkedList &ll ); 
    void insertHead( int item ); // insert at the head of the list 
    int count(int searchFor, const LinkedList &ll); 
    void moveNode(LinkedList &other, LinkedList &currentList); 


private: 
    class Node // inner class for a linked list node 
    { 
        public: 
        Node( int item, Node *n ); 
        int data; // the data item in a node 
    Node *next; // a pointer to the next node in the list 
}; 

Node *head; // the head of the list 
}; 

LinkedList::Node::Node(int item, Node *n)
{
    data = item;
    next = n;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const LinkedList &ll)
{
    LinkedList::Node *current;
    for(current = ll.head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
    {
        os << current->data << " ";
    }
}

int LinkedList::count(int searchFor, const LinkedList &ll)
{
    LinkedList::Node *current;
    current = ll.head;
    int howmanytimes = 0;
    while(current != NULL){
        if(current->data == searchFor)
        {
            howmanytimes++;
        }
    }
    cout << searchFor << " appears in " << ll << " | " << howmanytimes << "time(s)" << endl;
}

void moveNode(LinkedList &other, LinkedList &currentList) 
{ 
    LinkedList::Node *current = other.head; 
    if(current!=NULL) 
    { 
        current->next = currentList.head; 
    } 

} 

void LinkedList::insertHead(int item)
{
    head = new Node(item, head);
}
```

Comment: `void LinkedList::moveNode(LinkedList &other, LinkedList &currentList) ` should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You are not qualifying the class name in the `moveNode()` implementation:

```
// note the LinkedList::
void LinkedList::moveNode(LinkedList &other, LinkedList &currentList)
{ 
    LinkedList::Node *current = other.head; 
    if(current!=NULL) 
    { 
        current->next = currentList.head; 
    } 
}
```

That being said, this implementation does not match your description:

> a function that removes the head node of a linked list and makes it the head of another linked list

An implementation that actually does what that says would look something more like this:

```
void LinkedList::moveNode(LinkedList &other, LinkedList &currentList)
{ 
    LinkedList::Node *current = other.head; 
    if (current != NULL) 
    { 
        other.head = current->next;
        current->next = currentList.head; 
        currentList.head = current; 
    } 
}
```

That being said, this method should be renamed to something like `moveHead()` instead.  And since it is not accessing anything via the `this` pointer, it could even be declared `static`. Otherwise, I would suggest re-implementing it to remove the `currentList` parameter at least, eg:

```
void LinkedList::moveHead(LinkedList &other)
{ 
    LinkedList::Node *newhead = other.head; 
    if (newhead != NULL) 
    { 
        other.head = newhead->next;
        newhead->next = this->head; 
        this->head = newhead; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: While your answer is perfectly OK, the question's still crap.

Comment: Perhaps, but our job here is to answer questions as they are actually asked.  Whether they are asking the right thing or not is another matter.

Comment: Well, our job here is also moderating, and kicking crappy questions out. That's what I have actually done, leaving a helpful comment for the OP.